Integration without partitions of unity
Most text that deal with integration of forms on manifolds use partitions of unity, which is a very nice and intuitive analytic approach. However, it is, as far as I am aware, also possible to define integral of a form on a manifold by cutting it into a finite number of images of domains of integration and pulling back the form. I would assume that it is always possible to do thus. We could even take these domains to be simplices. But all of this is quite hard to prove. So instead this idea of cutting a manifold into simpler pieces is presented as a corollary of the partitions of unity approach.
I am wondering whether you are aware of a text that would take the above described approach ground up. I think this would be very fun to read.

Another approach would be to endow your connected manifold with a complete Riemannian metric and pull everything back via the exponential map: you obtain a chart that covers everything up to a measure zero set. However, this also uses partitions of unity in some sense, because you need to prove the existence of a Riemannian metric.

@Didier, wow, that sounds super cool. Any good reference you could suggest?

My favourite is Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine's Riemannian geometry, but Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds is another excellent reference.

I also prefer using a decomposition of a manifold into simplices or rectangular regions with smooth faces to define an integral. I find this approach to br more geometric and viiew partitions of unity as a technical trick. If you assume such a decomposition, then it is easy to define the integral. And the definition works for a manifold with boundary. The catch, however, is that the existence of such a decomposition is a difficult theorem in differential topology. When I teach this, I assume that fact and proceed using the decomposition. Rectangular regions are the easiest to use.

@Deane, I too feel that such an approach would be more geometric. Do you by any chance have a recording of your lectures or publicly available lecture notes on the topic?

Alas, I have nothing available that I can make public. But you can work this out fairly easily for rectangles on a surface. In hihgher dimensions it's best if you assume $k$-dimensional faces are glued to $k$-dimensional faces. and use rectangles instead of simplices because it's easy to define an integral over rectangles.
